# Jacobian of F(X)=XBX involving kronecker product.

Tags: matrices, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, kronecker-product

I'm trying to prove the following:

Let $X_{m\times m}$ be a symmetric matrix of variables. Find the Jacobian, defined as:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial vec{X'}}vec{F}$$

where $F(X)=XBX$ , where $B_{m\times m}$ is a symmetric matrix of constants. Answer: ($XB\otimes I_m$)+($I_m\otimes XB$). Where $\otimes$ refers to the Kronecker product.

My attempt:

\begin{align*}
    vec{F} &= vec{XBX} \\
           &= (X'\otimes X)vec{B} \\
           &= (X\otimes X)vec{B}
\end{align*}

Where "vec" refers to the vec operator.
So, the jacobian is given by:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial(X)'}(X\otimes X)vec{B}
$$

But, I don't know what to do next. Any suggestion please? Thanks!

Comment: Edit I edited your post to try to fix the formatting, but I don't understand how you placed the arrows.  Sometimes $B$ is written $\vec{B}$ and sometimes not.  In the jacobian, $X$ has an arrow, but nowhere else.  Please check that I haven't accidentally messed things up.

Comment: that's weird, because I didn't put arrows.

Comment: The source had many places where you had written `$vec(X)$` and I assumed you meant to say `$\vec{X}$` which comes out as $\vec{X}$  What did you want it to look like?  (Actually, it was usually $B$, not $X$.)

Comment: I wanted just vec(X), but I think that there was a problem with the code, that changes vec(X) with \vec

Comment: Sorry.  I'm not familiar with the vec operator, and I thought it was supposed to be a typesetting command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the differential **before** applying the vec operator.
$$\eqalign{
dF &= dX\,BX + XB\,dX \\
df &= \big((BX)^T\otimes I\big)\,dx + \big(I\otimes XB\big)\,dx \\
   &= \big((XB\otimes I) + (I\otimes XB)\big)\,dx \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
   &= \big((XB\otimes I) + (I\otimes XB)\big) \\
}$$
where
$$f={\rm vec}(F),\quad x={\rm vec}(X)$$

Comment: Why $dF$ its equal to that? I don't get that $BdX$ part. I thought it was $XBdX$

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It was a typo.

Comment: Could you explain why we have that $df$ ? Wich property did you use?

Comment: $df$ denotes the differential of the vector $f={\rm vec}(F)$, just as $dF$ denotes the differential of the matrix $F$.

Comment: OK. thanks. In my problem, the jacobian has $\partial vec(X^{T})$   it would be equal with $\partial vec(X)$ without the transpose?

Comment: In that case you must use the [Commutation Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) associated with Kronecker products $${\rm vec}(X^T) = K\;{\rm vec}(X)$$

Comment: Actually what you have in your denominator is $d\Big[{\rm vec}(X)\Big]^T$ so there's no need for the Commutation matrix.